# dotnet core System.Threading.Timer only fires once

Tags: linux, .net-core, raspberry-pi2

Working on a Linux service and when I setup the `System.Threading.Timer` it only fires once. The interesting part is it only fires once on Linux. When debugging on Windows it continually fires. For the time being I've gotten around this by using `System.Timers` instead. Just curious if others have seen this.

```
private void StartTimers()
    {
        _autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _tm = new Timer(_client.ProcessQueue, _autoEvent, 1000, 10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit Application");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: it should be major issue of .net core if reproducible, right?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, I am working on a dotnet core application running on a rasperry pi with Debian. It was supposed to take a screenshot every minute but the System.Threading.Timer only fired the first time. Following your suggestion I tried the System.Timers class and found that it worked. The timer fires every minute now as expected. So I can confirm that this solution works.

```
    public class Client
    {
        public Client()
        {
            // start the timer in the class constructor
            StartScreenshotting();
        }

        private void StartScreenshotting()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            // 60000ms is one minute
            timer.Interval = 60000;
            timer.Elapsed += TakeScreenshot;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void TakeScreenshot(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            // take screenshot logic
        }
    }
```

Comment: Following **whos?** suggestion?

Comment: The suggestion of Clarke76 who asked the question. He wrote: "For the time being I've gotten around this by using System.Timers instead."